# Gutenberg. How To Register A Custom Block Style For Specific Post Type Only

Tags: block-editor

For the `core/paragraph`-Block, I would like to register a custom style. This is working fine with

```
const { registerBlockStyle } = wp.blocks;
wp.domReady( () => {
    registerBlockStyle( 'core/paragraph', {
        name: 'lead',
        label: 'Lead'
    } );
} );
```

Now I want this custom style to be applied only to certain post types, e.g. only to post type "post". Therefor I have to access the current post type in the editor. But this is not working:

```
const { registerBlockStyle } = wp.blocks;
const { useSelect } = wp.data;

wp.domReady( () => {
    // This is not working:
    const postType = useSelect( select => select( 'core/editor').getCurrentPostType() );

    if ( postType === 'post' ) {

        registerBlockStyle( 'core/paragraph', {
            name: 'lead',
            label: 'Lead'
        } );
    }
} );
```

All I got is an React-minify-error in the console:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

I suppose I have to wrap everything into a component or something.

**How can I make this working?**

#### Alternative option

I could generate a separate javascript file which is only enqueued and loaded if the current post type is "post".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I make this working?

Not sure if there's a better way, but I'd use [`subscribe()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/#subscribe) in the `@wordpress/data` package:

```js
const { registerBlockStyle } = wp.blocks;
const { subscribe, select } = wp.data;

wp.domReady( () => {
    const unsubscribe = subscribe( () => {
        const postType = select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostType();

        // 1. Unsubscribe once we've got the post type.
        if ( postType ) {
            unsubscribe();
            console.log( `Post type: ${ postType }. Unsubscribed.` );

            // 2. Register the block style if the post type is 'post'.
            if ( 'post' === postType ) {
                registerBlockStyle( 'core/paragraph', {
                        name: 'lead',
                        label: 'Lead'
                } );
            }
        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was not aware of the existence of the observable pattern in Gutenberg.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `subscribe()`? Is that more failsafe? For me `wp.block.select('core/editor').getCurrentPostType()` also works without subscribe. So I’m wondering if there’s something I’m missing. Can `wp.domReady()` run before the current post type is set up?

Comment: @Gchtr just now via inline `<script>` I tried on WordPress 5.8.1 with `wp.domReady( () => console.log( 'post type is', wp.data.select( 'core/editor').getCurrentPostType() ) )` and the console showed `post type is null`. But if `getCurrentPostType()` is called manually via the console after the page is loaded, then yes, you'd get the correct post type because the editor's initialization has been completed.